# Spring boot jpa query select как сделать

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data

Мне необходимо, в зависимости от того, чего хочет пользователь, фильтровать мои посты (типа в соц сетях) по title, authorId, tags, отсортировать по названию поля в классе, указать order и лимитировать кол-во постов для постраничного отображения. Пользователь в адресной строке вводит все эти параметры `GET /articles?skp=...&limit=...&q=title&authorId=...&tags=tag1,tag2&order=desc&sorted=field_name` , **НО может и не водить вовсе, или ввести только некоторые из них**. Мой контроллер выглядит так:

```
@GetMapping("/articles")
    public List<Article> getAllPublicPosts(@RequestParam(name = "skip", required = false, defaultValue = "0") Long skip,
                                           @RequestParam(name = "limit", required = false, defaultValue = "10") Long limit,
                                           @RequestParam(name = "q", required = false, defaultValue = "") String postTitle,
                                           @RequestParam(name = "author", required = false, defaultValue = "0") Long authorId,
                                           @RequestParam(name = "sort", required = false, defaultValue = "none") String fieldName,
                                           @RequestParam(name = "order", required = false, defaultValue = "asc") String order,
                                           @RequestParam(name = "tags", required = false, defaultValue = "") String[] tags) {

        return articleService.getAllPublicPosts(skip, limit, postTitle, authorId, fieldName, order, tags);

    }
```

Я могу сделать все в коде, но для этого мне приходится доставать все значения в список. А что, если кол-во постов будет превышать Integer.MAX_VALUE? А что , если постов настолько много не будет, но по-прежнему много? Тогда код будет работать супер медленно

Важно в контроллере то, что есть дефолтные значения. Я бы хотела сделать такой `@Query-select`, чтобы, в случае чего, он бы игнорировал некоторые из `@RequestParam`, а точнее `postTitle, authorId, fieldName`, иначе при выборке он может мне ничего и не вернуть, но совсем не знаю как. И не знаю, возможно ли это в принципе. Если пилить для каждого случая отдельный метод в ArticleRepo, их станет слишком много

Comment: способов много... я бы посоветовал вам использовать что-то типа criteria для построения такого запроса, а сам запрос строить , используя паттерн цепочка обязанностей либо декоратор. убьете сразу двух зайцев: 1) разберетесь что тако criteria , 2) получите опыт работы с паттернами проектирования. очень неплохо, как по мне, особенно,если проект учебный

Comment: @ Anastasiya и еще... у вас такое большое количество параметров, что , как по мне, целесообразно использовать дто. данный объект будет проще передавать в качестве аргумента в методы (чем множество указанных параметров), кроме того, количество этих параметров может меняться и это самое неприятное. в случае с дто вы будете менять поля только самой дто, а в вашем - переписывать сигнатуры методов, использующих эти параметры.

Comment: упер! большое спасибо!) то что нужно